# Threading foreach that abides by async/await methods inside said foreach

Tags: c#

I have been looking up a way to itterate through a foreach with multiple threads, for example, let's say I have a list

```
public List<MYclass> All()
{
     // fill the list
}


Private async Task Main()
{
     foreach(All() as whatever)
    {
        await method();
        await method2();
    }
}

private async Task method()
{
     //do some stuff
     // more stuff
     await another();
}


private async Task method2()
{
     //do some stuff
     // more stuff
     await another2();
}

private async Task another()
{
     //await client to do whatever
}

private async Task another2()
{
     //await client to do whatever
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

> List item 1 = thread1
>
> List item 2 = thread2
>
> List item 3 = thread3
>
> ...etc depending on how many threads I have

I've been looking around with no hope, I found Parrellel.foreach, but that doesn't wait for awaits, because once it hits the await, it complete the whole action then starts the foreach again, so how could I go about achieving what I want? Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Do you want to proceed wiht the next item in `All` after all the method has done their work ?

Comment: Instead of `await method();`, why not `tasks.Add(method());` etc. and then call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say, is that async/await code isn't really [multi threaded](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) . I think it sort of creates another thread sometimes, but its mainly meant to alleviate blocking in code.

I tend to think mixing multithreading and async is actually a bit of a pain because exception handling is a bit harder and less predictable. You'd be better off using Parallel foreach, and taking async off the method call definitions. Or just calling .Result inside the parallel foreach to make that code execute synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

"Threads" are too low-level a concept to think about these days - after all, when a method is `await`ing, it doesn't even use a thread. Instead, you want to think about "tasks" and "operations".

In this case, what you want is asynchronous concurrency (not parallel/threaded concurrency). First, define the (single) operation that you want done for each item:

```
private async Task ProcessAsync(MyClass item)
{
  await method();
  await method2();
}
```

Next, to start operations for all tasks concurrently, you can use `Select`:

```
private async Task Main()
{
  var tasks = All().Select(ProcessAsync).ToArray();
}
```

and then, to (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete, use `await Task.WhenAll`:

```
private async Task Main()
{
  var tasks = All().Select(ProcessAsync).ToArray();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```